# How to Apply style to data fetched from MySQL database in php

Tags: php, mysql, css

I am trying a find and replace functionality for PHP/MySQL, and the first thing what i am doing is displaying all the data from database on a page and then display the same. below is the query i am using to do the same:

```
'SELECT "office_phone" as col_name, id, office_phone as search_string, trim(replace(concat(" ",LOWER(office_phone)," ")," '.$find.' "," '.$replace.' ")) as replace_string  FROM `employees` WHERE ( office_phone like "'.$find.' %" OR office_phone like "% '.$find.' %" OR office_phone like "% '.$find.'" OR office_phone LIKE "'.$find.'")';
```

now if i found the string as 'Raj' it will display all the fields have Raj string from  column "office_phone".. now i want to make found string as bold (only found string) such as Raj office number is 123456789.. in this only 'Raj' should get bold.. can anyone please help quickly... 
 Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is basically just "apply styling to an arbitrary chunk of emitted HTML" + "select search string". Solve accordingly; this question is kind of weirdly specific.

Comment: Actually you can create style tag to that particular content you are getting for example <font color="#FF0000" size="+5" ><?php echo $content;?></font>.....hope this will clear your issue

Comment: this i already tried this make my complete sentence/content as bold however i want only a particular string to get bold

Comment: I can give you a logic i think it may helps you.....first explode  the whole string then compare with the search value and the explode value when it was compared with the search value and the explode value then apply style

Answer (score 0):

This should do your work.
If you want to make it case sensitive then use:

```
str_replace
```

insted of

```
str_ireplace
```

.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$str="hello this is a good book. Hello, did you like the book. helloare you there?";
$strrep="hello";
$str = str_ireplace($strrep,'<b>'. $strrep.'</b>',$str);
echo "$str";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "I am trying a find and replace functionality for PHP/MySQL, and the first thing what i am doing is displaying all the data from database on a page and then display the same. below is the query i am using to do the same";
$searchingFor = "/" . $searchQuery . "/i";
$replacePattern = "<b>$0<\/b>";
preg_replace($searchingFor, $replacePattern, $string);
```